# Zero cokernel and epimorphisms in semi-abelian categories

Tags: category-theory, universal-property

I'm dealing with a question that I can't prove or disprove.

> Is it true that in a semi-abelian category (in the sense of Janelidze) a normal monomorphism with null cokernel is an epimorphism?

I know that the fact is trivially true in the category of **Grp**, since cokernels are quotients, but I don't know if this fact generalizes to the semi-abelian setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a semi-abelian category, a normal monomorphism is the kernel of its cokernel. So if said cokernel is zero, its kernel is an isomorphism, hence also an epimorphism.